# Visual Studio Code won't run python requests script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have this simple script but it simply doesn't seem to be running. I've tried with and without debugging, and it seems to go through it but it ignores the prints and the write csv portion, it's like it does nothing. I have a regular installation of VS code and python (no anaconda).

The code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import locale
import csv

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

URL = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries'
html_page = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')
get_table = soup.find('table', id='main_table_countries_today')
get_table_data = get_table.tbody.find_all("tr")

dic = {}
for i in range(len(get_table_data)):
    try:
        key = get_table_data[i].find_all('a', href=True)[0].string
    except:
        key = get_table_data[i].find_all('td')[0].string

    values = [j.string for j in get_table_data[i].find_all('td')]
    dic[key] = values
    print(key)
pt = dic["Portugal"]
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

output = [today, locale.atoi(pt[1]), locale.atoi(pt[3]), locale.atoi(pt[5])]

print(output)

with open('C:/Users/HP/Documents/Scripts/coronavirus/data.csv','a+', newline='') as write_obj:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(write_obj)
    csv_writer.writerow(output)

print(output)
print("Done!")
```

What I see in the terminal:

[image: Error message]

Comment: What if you replace the script with a single `print` function call?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood then it will run that line, no problem (just tried it)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe it is fully reproducible except for the csv part where you'd need to change the file and create a csv of your own. But even if I comment that whole part out, the problem still happens.

Comment: Okay, is there anything else you can comment out and you still get the problem. I'm going after the *"minimal"* part of [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the file? Does that get hit?